# compare date only part from the string

Tags: php

I have two strings (read from an XML file), say '**2014-10-17**T11:17:44' and '**2014-10-17**T16:19:15'. I want to compare them using only the date part (without time). I already tried ...script below

```
if(file_exists($xmlFullFilename)) {
        if($entryTimeNode->format("Y-m-d") = $entryTimeNode->format("Y-m-d")){
                    ( appends to the exisiting file ....)
                    $xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
                    $tmp = split(" ", $entryTime);
                $dateString = $tmp[0] . "T" . $tmp[1];
                $entryTimeNode = $xmlDoc->createElement("EntryTime", $dateString);
}
 else {
        //create a new xml file .
}}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<Incidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Count="2" Date="2014-10-24" Time="12:05:39" FileName="2014-10-24_Brook_Retail_Park.xml">
      <Incident>
      <EntryTime>2014-10-17T11:17:44</EntryTime>
      </Incident>
    <Incident>
<EntryTime>2014-10-17T16:19:15</EntryTime>
    </Incident></Incidents>
```

Comment: There's no space in the strings, why are you splitting on space instead of `T`?

Comment: Your date comparison `if` should be `==` not `=`.

Comment: And you're comparing the same things, they'll always be equal.

Answer (score 0):

My soluction is

```
$date = "2014-10-17T11:17:44";
$date2 = "2014-10-17T16:19:15";

$date = new DateTime($date);
$date2 = new DateTime($date2);


$diff = $date->diff($date2);

if((int)$diff->format('%y%m%d')==0)
{
    // Dates are equal
}
```